# How to lock a MacBook Pro (Touch Bar version) with a short cut key?

Tags: macbook-pro

I used to lock my MacBook Air by Shitt-Control-Eject shortcut key. After replacing the Air with a Touch Bar MacBook Pro, there is no Eject key anymore.

How can I lock it with a shortcut key?

Answer (score -1):

Use `Shift+Ctrl+Power` shortcut.

Comment: It doesn't work on the new Macbook Pro with Touchbar late 2016 anymore.